# Differences between MinRoles and Custom Role

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

In SharePoint 2019 there are MinRoles to be select when we create new SharePoint Farm or join new servers to Existing Farm here waht are the main differences by performance and what is the archetecural difference between MinRoles and Custom Role.
As custom role have more control to disable services but MinRoles not have option to disable services.
Example is that when certain cases we dont require Search service application and server creates with application with search role Is SharePoint  assign any resources for search components and it cause an y perfomrance issue

Answer (score 0):

MinRole is a new farm topology based on a set of predefined server roles introduced in SharePoint Server 2016.
Custom rloe is one of MinRole Server Roles. The main functions are:
Hosts Services that haven't integrated with MinRole yet
Farm administrator manages services on this role instead of MinRole
For more details, Please refer to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/overview-of-minrole-server-roles-in-sharepoint-server
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/description-of-minrole-and-associated-services-in-sharepoint-server-2016